# how to compare values from different tables with same name mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, datatable

i have 2 tables

table A

```
Question|Answer
-------------------
    a   |  y
```

table B

```
Type  |  Question
------------------
  3   |   a
---------------
  1   |   b
```

how do i check what type question A is from Table A by looking at it from table B?
i want to check if question a from table A is type 3 (do this) if it is type 1 (do this)
cant find the right query

```
maybe Select type from table B where tableA.question = tableB.question
```

Comment: Explain what (do this) and (do that) mean exactly!!! Because there are things you can do in SQL (like filtering and sorting) but there are others you can't

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.Type FROM TableA a, TableB b WHERE a.Question=b.Question
```

Comment: how do i do it with the if statements?

Comment: if statement using PHP ?

Comment: what do you use ? mysql or prepared statements?

Answer (score 0):

Effectively what you need to do here is perform a join in your query, so that you return the type along with the question and answer in your result set.

You can use the following SQL;

```
SELECT a.question, a.answer, b.type FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.question=b.question
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how do i do this with ifs the way i need though? like if question a from table A is type 3 (do this)

Comment: If what? In PHP or Mysql? Need more information than what you've written so far.

Comment: I'll assume you know how to get the result. You simply say, `if($row['type'] == 3) { do stuff } else { do something else }`

Answer (score 0):

You can JOIN both tables and then perform the logic in PHP.

```
SELECT 
    a.question as question,
    a.answer as answer,
    b.type as type
FROM
    table_a a, table_b b
WHERE
    a.question = b.question;
```